# Do journey milestones serve any purpose aside from trophies/achievements?

Tags: no-mans-sky

In No Man's Sky, completing milestones gives you trophies/achievements, but is there any practical purpose to them in-game? Is there a milestone rank required to complete the game?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only use for these milestones is for finishing the game via the Atlas Path. In order to achieve the Atlas Path ending, you will need to be rank Magellan or higher, which means you will need a cumulative journey milestone rank of 50+, as described in the Atlas Path guide [here](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2016-08-23-no-mans-sky-atlas-path-what-is-the-atlas-path-how-to-reach-the-atlas-ending-and-atlas-path-rewards).

> Hit at least 50 journey milestones - you'll need the title of "MAGELLAN" to fully complete the Atlas Path, although each Atlas Interface you commune with will require another rank up in your milestone achievements to continue 'submitting' to it's will.

Also, Polo will only give you a blueprint (including the blueprint for the Atlas Pass V1) if you have reached certain milestones, as described [here](http://www.carlsguides.com/nomanssky/path-of-the-atlas.php).

> Polo will always offer you a blueprint, Atlaspass V1 on the first encounter, which greatly helps you to upgrade your exosuit's capacity (every starbase has a door that is locked and features an upgrade). In order to get the blueprint from him, you must possess data. First it's learning a few alien words, next meeting aliens, then having earned so many credits, and number of pirates killed.

Other than this, there is no practical use for these milestones.

It's worth noting that it is impossible to beat the game without achieving a single milestone, however, as warping to the center of the galaxy would net you a few milestones for number of warps along the way, even without following the Atlas Path.

Comment: re: the linked info, I am "kind of sure" the starbase doors require (at least) lvl 2. The open-air supply drops are lvl1. I had the bug where I found v2 but can't craft it, and I have never been able to open any atlas doors aside from drops.

Comment: @Yorik in my experience, the V1 will open one door in every space station, leading to an inventory upgrade (exactly the same as if you'd found a drop pod on the surface).